# Linear dependency - 3 vectors in $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $v1, v2, v3 \in R^2$ and $Sp(\{{v1, v2\}}) = Sp(\{{v1, v3\}})$.
I need to prove or disapprove:
**1**. $\{{v2, v3\}}$ is a linear dependent set
**2**. $Sp(\{{v2, v3\}}) = R^2$
1- I want to somehow enter $v1, v2, v3$ into matrix and show that I get 2 equivalent rows meaning the rows are linear dependent and then I proved what they asked. 2- I want to say that if $v2, v3$ are linear dependent they can never be a base of $R^2$ therefore they are not equivalent to $R^2$
I'm not sure about the explanations... Is it right to just write a matrix? How do I explain that? Is it even correct? And about 2, am I right saying what I said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are linearly dependent if and only if one is a scalar multiple of the other. If $Span(\{v_1,v_2\})=Span(\{v_1,v_3\})$, must it be the case that $v_2$ is a scalar multiple of $v_3$ or vice versa? Try to think of simple examples.

For 2: the answer to this will depend on what you determine for question 1. Your logic is correct that if $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly dependent they cannot span $\mathbb{R}^2$, but you have not determined that $v_2$ and $v_3$ must be linearly dependent. It suffices to find just one example where $v_2$ and $v_3$ don't span $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you think of a simple one? (Note $v_2$ and $v_3$ will have to be scalar multiples of one another... might as well make them equal.)

Comment: hmm... if $v1 = (1, 0), v2 = (0, 1), v3 = (1, 2)$ it contradicts question 1... Am I right?

Comment: Right, that counterexample will work to show that 1 is false.

Comment: But then 2 is true... From what I understand you're saying it is false. Am I wrong?

Comment: You have to be careful here. What you've actually shown is that 1 is not necessarily true, that is, there is at least one instance in which it is false. But it's not always false. There ARE examples when $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: So how do I approach number 2?

Comment: Read my answer again. Can you think of an example where $v_2$ and $v_3$ don't span $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes! They will be linear dependent but that's ok. Thank you (:

Comment: You're welcome!